# Accessing a matrix element by matrix[(a, b), c] instead of matrix[a, b, c]

Tags: python, numpy

I want to achieve the following:

1. Have a AxBxC matrix (where A,B,C are
   integers).
2. Access that matrix not as matrix[a,
   b, c] but as matrix[(a, b), c], this
   is, I have two variables, var1 = (x,
   y) and var2 = z and want access my
   matrix as matrix[var1, var2].

How can this be done? I am using numpy matrix, if it makes any difference.

I know I could use matrix[var1[0], var1[1], var2], but if possible I'd like to know if there is any other more elegant way.

Thanks!

Comment: Add that as asnwer and I'll rate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `var1 = (x,y)`, and `var2 = z`, you can use

```
matrix[var1][var2]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simply subclass the NumPy matrix type, with a new class of your own; and overload the `__getitem__()` nethod to accept a tuple.  Something like this:

```
class SpecialMatrix(np.matrix):
    def __getitem__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3=None):
        try:
            i, j = arg1
            k = arg2
            assert(arg3 is None)
            x = super(SpecialMatrix, self).__getitem__(i, j, k)
        except TypeError:
            assert(arg3 is not None)
            return super(SpecialMatrix, self).__getitem__(arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

And do something similar with `__setitem__()`.

I'm not sure if `__getitem__()` takes multiple arguments like I'm showing here, or if it takes a tuple, or what.  I don't have NumPy available as I write this answer, sorry.

EDIT: I re-wrote the example to use `super()` instead of directly calling the base class.  It has been a while since I did anything with subclassing in Python.

EDIT: I just looked at the accepted answer.  That's totally the way to do it.  I'll leave this up in case anyone finds it educational, but the simple way is best.